# How to modify single elements of PGFPlotsTable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, cell

I want to create a table with some values. Afterwards I want to replace one
element of the table and display a plot.
The nearest I get, you can see below in the minimum example.
So there are two basic questions:

1. Why does the table show the modified value, but not the graph?
2. How could I modify the table after the first plot and then plot
   it again, say with number 30 in row 10 column 2?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/x/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}},
    create on use/y/.style={create col/expr={10*\pgfplotstablerow}},
    every row 12 column y/.style={preproc/expr=(30)},}      %%%%% manipulated value
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x,y}]{15}\loadedtable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};         %%%%% plot shows the old value
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/x/.style={string type}]{\loadedtable}  %%%%% table shows the new value
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Maybe a sketch what you want to achieve might be helpful (at least I) I have no idea what you want to draw.

Comment: Hi, is not it easier  to make a table in ```.csv``` and then just print it near the plot?

Comment: @Roland: I think that OP's question is more theoretical - Why does this happen!? The MWE illustrates the problem perfectly.

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh: I do not think this is about what is easiest. I do also not see how it is easier/safer to let LaTeX modify a .csv file

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behaviour is that the style which replaces the value is not manipulating the table directly, but rather its output when it is typeset.

In the following code you can see that the value of cell (12,*y*) internally is still 120, although it has been manipulated using `preproc/expr`. I take it that the modifications set by `preproc/expr` are only invoked upon typesetting the value using `\pgfplotstabletypeset`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/x/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}},
    create on use/y/.style={create col/expr={10*\pgfplotstablerow}},
    every row 12 column y/.style={preproc/expr=(30)}} %%%%% manipulated value
    
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x, y}]{15}\loadedtable

\pgfplotstablegetelem{12}{y}\of{\loadedtable}
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {\loadedtable};       %%%%% plot shows the old value
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\loadedtable}  %%%%% table shows the new value

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In order to really change the value of the relevant cell, you need to assign it already upon its creation, that is, during the assignment via `create col/expr`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/x/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}},
    create on use/y/.style={create col/expr={(\pgfplotstablerow == 12 ? 30 : 10*\pgfplotstablerow)}}} %%%%% manipulated value upon creation of column
    
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x, y}]{15}\loadedtable

\pgfplotstablegetelem{12}{y}\of{\loadedtable}
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\loadedtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Now, you ask how you can first print the table with the original values and then again after having manipulated the values. Since the values of the table are never changed, this is not really possible. But you can do something similar by creating a new column to the existing table to which you assign (again via `create col/expr`) the other set of values.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/x/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}},
    create on use/y/.style={create col/expr={10*\pgfplotstablerow}}}

\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x, y}]{15}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\loadedtable}

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/expr={(\pgfplotstablerow == 12 ? 30 : 10*\pgfplotstablerow)}]
    {yy}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[y=yy] {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={x, yy}, columns/{yy}/.style={column name=y}]{\loadedtable}

\end{document}
```

In fact, you could of course already at the very beginning when you call `\pgfplotstableset` assign a third column the other values using `create on use/yy/.style={create col/expr=`...`}`.

[image]